# Best way to store financial data together with news

Tags: time-series, finance

My question is if there is a DBMS that allows storing financial data (i.e. timestamp+value) together with small text fragments.

These small fragments will not be very long, but it might help an algorithm to predict changes in the future. In summary, I wonder if you can suggest me what it is the best way to massively store timestamps+numeric value+(optional)text fragment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how "massive" are we talking about here?  And what's the use case? do you need real-time querying or just use for normal machine learning training? Your question is too generic. It's like asking "what is the best car" without specifying your budget and use of the car. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that (almost) any DBMS will be able to store that information for you.

I use Microsoft SQL and you can store the record with a specified or system calculated date-time, a column for the numeric value and you can store the story text in one of four ways:

- Plain text as a NVARCHAR
- structured text as XML (or JSON if you are on SQL2016 or above)
- Filestream if the data format is binary (normally an image, audio or video)
- As a reference to a file on disk

MSSQL is an RDBMS (relational database management system) Others in this classification are Oracle, MySql, Postgress.  There is another school of database classified as NOSQL or Document Databases and these include Mongo, CouchDB, DocumentDB and RavenDB.  These differ from RDBMS in the way they store data and manage the relationships (e.g. find all the articles relating to company X in the time period 1st April to 6th June)

I would suggest that if you don't know how you are going to want to process the data in the future, look at storing it in a NOSQL database as it provides much greater flexibility of record structure.  Most can be installed on-premise with a free / open source licence and most are also available on a hosted platform for a relatively small sum.  Many of the RDBMS (esp Oracle and MSSQL) are exceeding expensive for this sort of project.  That said, Azure SQL - the hosted version of SQL can be had for as little as $8 per month depending on your storage requirements.